# How do I install the Azure SDK for an iOS Swift project?

Tags: ios, swift, azure, cloud, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to install Azure [for existing app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-ios-get-started-data/) in my xcode project but I'm unable to achieve. Can somebody tell me the procedure to follow Azure in an iOS Swift project?

Answer (score -1):

Found it.

There's a tutorial and demo-application on Microsoft's website, you can find it here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-ios-get-started-data/

> In this tutorial, you download an existing app that stores data
>   in-memory and change it to work with an Azure mobile service.

Once you download the demo application, you'll find the framework in the project folder:

[image]

Download: [WindowsAzureMovileServices-Framework](https://www.codebeaulieu.com/21/WindowsAzureMovileServices-Framework)